# Directional derivative and differential

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently studying Analysis with several variables and, after practising some exercises in which I had to obtain the directional derivative at a certain point $x$ for any vector $u$, in the solution it was written that the same expression for the directional derivatve I had calculated was the differential at that point. I knew that there was a relationship between both, but I am now under the question that if both concepts are the same, diferring only in "the context". I'll provide the exact exercise:

Given the usual scalar product and a linear application $A, f(x) = \langle x,Ax \rangle + bx$, for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b$ a $1 x n$ column. I was able to find the directional derivative of a vector $u$ without any difficulty: $D_uf(x) = [x^t(A + A^t) + b]u$. However, in the text it says that the differential at the point $x$ is exactly that.

Does this happen because, given the definition of differentiability at a point $x$, $D_uf(x)$ is linear and applied for $h$ such that $||h|| \rightarrow 0$, it satisfies the limit of the definition of differentiability? Is the only difference the fact that the directional derivative at a point receives vectors and the differential points?

Comment: What is the definition of “differential”?

Comment: The differential at a point $a$ of a function $f$ is a linear application $d_a(x)$ such that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-d_a(h)}{h} = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to have had the time to clean this answer up so it's not so repetitive.

I don't believe there's necessarily one universal definition of either of these notions which would allow us to definitively say these are or are not the same. People like me working in Banach spaces would have one direction of a directional derivative which is formally distinct from a differential, whereas differential geometers could have a definition of directional derivative different from mine which makes the two coincide. The derivative and the differential are both attempts to linearize a function. For me, the distinction comes in when we ask how exactly linear structure enters the problem.

I think the notion of a directional derivative pops up more when the domain itself has the linear structure, and "differential" might be more common for manifolds. However, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is both a vector space and a manifold, and it is canonically identifiable with its own tangent space, so these two notions essentially become the same thing.

Let's informally cover both sides: Imagine an open set $U$, a function $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$, and a base point $p\in U$. Suppose we have a vector space $V$ consisting of directions $u\in V$. Roughly speaking, the derivative is (in the best case) a linear functional (sometimes called a covector) $df_p:V\to\mathbb{R}$ (in other words, $df_p\in V^*$), differences $f(q)-f(p)\approx df_p(u)$ if $q$ is "near" $p$ and in the "direction" of $q$.

In one situation, $U$ could be a subset of a vector space $X$, in which case the domain itself has the linear structure. The direction vectors $u$ come from $V=X$, and $df_p\in X^*$ is a linear functional on the domain. Here, the formal result is that $f(p+u)-f(p)\approx df_p(u)$ for small $u$. Because $U$ itself has the linear structure that is, because $V=X$, $p+u$ makes sense. This is the context which I deal with more often. In the case of $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ (which we typically think about as column vectors), a linear functional acting on the column vectors takes the form of a row vector and the action has the form $u\mapsto vu$ for some $v$. In this case, $$v=(\frac{\partial}{\partial f}{x^1}(p),\ldots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^n}(p)),$$ since $$f(p+u)-f(p)\approx \sum_{i=1}^n u_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p)=(\frac{\partial}{\partial f}{x^1}(p),\ldots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^n}(p))\begin{pmatrix}u^1 \\ \vdots \\ u^n\end{pmatrix}.$$ In this special case, the coordinates $x^1,\ldots,x^n$ in which we express this action are canonical. Generally, coordinates are non-canonical.

In another situation, $U$ could be a subset of a manifold $M$, in which case $M$ need not have any linear structure. It is the tangent space $T_pM$ to $M$ at $p$ which has the linear structure, and this is where the directions come from. For example, $M$ could be a sphere, $p$ is a point on the sphere, and $T_pM$ is the tangent plane to the sphere at $p$. We will have a tangent vector $u\in T_pM=V$. Differentials are then members of the cotangent space $T_p^*M=V^*$. Here,
$p+u$ doesn't make sense, because $p$ is a point in $M$ and $u\in T_pM$. We have to explain/interpret what it means to travel away from $p$ in the direction of $u$ in order to make sense of the linearization. The formal way that we define this is to travel through $p$ with a smooth curve $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to U$ with $\varphi(0)=p$. This curve determines a direction $u\in T_pM\neq M$, and each direction $u$ arises from such a curve (and in the special case of $M=\mathbb{R}^n$, $T_pM\neq M$, but the two are canonically identifiable because we have maps of the form $\varphi(t)=p+tu$, which is clearly in the direction of $u$). Then the differences $f(q)-f(p)$ if $q$ is "in the direction of" $u$ will refer to $f(\varphi(h))-f(p)$, and this amounts to looking at $\frac{d(f\circ \varphi)}{dt}(0)$.  If $M=\mathbb{R}^n$, we have canonical coordinates, and we can write $\varphi=(\varphi^1,\ldots,\varphi^n)$ for smooth functions $\varphi^1,\ldots,\varphi^n$.  Then the direction determined by $\varphi$ can be identified with the vector $$u=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{d\varphi^1}{dt}(0) \\ \vdots \\\frac{d\varphi^n}{dt}(0)\end{pmatrix}.$$ Here, we've already cheated and written this as a member of $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead of the tangent space $T_p\mathbb{R}^n$, because the two are canonically identifiable. In the case of a general manifold, we do not have any canonical coordinates, so we have to fix a coordinate chart $x:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\varphi^i$ is replaced with $x^i\circ \varphi$, and the direction vector is $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d(x^i\circ \varphi)}{dt}(0) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}.$$

For a manifold, once we fix a chart $x=(x^1,\ldots,x^n):U\to \mathbb{R}^n$, this determines a (non-canonical) basis for the tangent space $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1},\ldots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}$. Every direction vector $u\in T_pM$ can be written as $u=\sum_{i=1}^n u^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, as described in the previous paragraph.  The differentials $dx^1,\ldots,dx^n$ are defined so that $$dx^i\Bigl(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Bigr)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & : i=j \\ 0 & : i\neq j.\end{array}\right.$$

Once we have this coordinate chart, if $W=x(U)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is its range, we can define a new function $F:W\to \mathbb{R}$ by letting $$F(x^1(q),\ldots,x^n(q))=f(q).$$ In other words, $F=f\circ x^{-1}$.  We can then run through the usual business with $F$ as we did in the previous paragraphs to get $$dF_p=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial F}{\partial x^1}(x(p)) & \ldots & \frac{\partial F}{\partial x^n}(x(p))\end{pmatrix},$$ so that if $q$ is "near" $p$ in the "direction" of $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (which means $x(q)\approx x(p)+u$, $$F(x(q))-F(x(p))\approx F(x(p)+u)-F(x(p))\approx \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i}(x(p)) u^i.$$  Then if we think about the tangent vector $$\sum_{i=1}^n u^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},$$ $df_p$ is the covector whose action on this tangent vector is the quantity above: $$df_p\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^n u^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Bigr)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i}(x(p))u^i,$$ which means $$df_p=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial (f\circ x^{-1})}{\partial x^i}(x(p))dx^i.$$

Dropping back to the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can again take $x$ to be the identity, in which case the row vector that we called $df_p$ has exactly the same coordinates as the differential that we called $df_p$ in the preceding paragraph. However, the derivative $df_p$ formally lives in $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$, while the differential $df_p$ formally lives in $(T_p\mathbb{R}^n)^*$.

Comment: I really apreciate the time you spent to write this answer for me, I am very grateful.